# High RAM usage.

Tags: 14.04, ram

`watch -n 5 free -m`provides me with:

```
Total: 7934

Free:6233
```

However, my system monitor says I'm using 50-60% just while running Chrome and Spotify? To me it seems a tad high.

I'm on a desktop PC, should not have this high RAM usage. Any way to see which sucks it up?

Comment: does this happen after you listen on spotify for a while?

Comment: Can you provide some screens (especially of the system monitor). Anyway, run `top` to show all processes..

Comment: Post the output of `top` in your question.

Comment: @rumesh no it's pretty consistent, I suspect it might be chrome though. Will test with Firefox and no spotify tomorrow.

Comment: @cbll the reason I asked is that every time the song changes on my laptop, It uses more RAM. I came across a command that can free up the memory that is being used

Comment: Chrome sometimes stutters and messes up(shifts through tabs, flickers) by itself, so I have to close and open it. Might this have a connection to this issue?

Comment: Check the exact process that is using memory using `top` command !

Comment: @SharadGautam How do I paste the output in here without the formatting being a mess? Sorry for noob questions.

Comment: Include your output inside `` like `this`

Answer (score 2):

Be conscious that some system monitors don't factor in cache and buffering. The is where the system transparently uses RAM to store things from disk, to make their second access faster. The cache is automagically reduced in size if you need more RAM. See my `free` output:

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         24110      19949       4161        366        900      14299
-/+ buffers/cache:       4749      19361
Swap:            0          0          0
```

At a glance it might look like I'm using almost 20GB of RAM, but 14GB of that is cache. It's the second line of values that show the actual system usage 4.5 used and 19.5 free.

Comment: What's your ram @Oli

Comment: @SharadGautam 24GB on this computer, though ~500MB has gone missing. I assume there's some Kernel overhead eating some.

Comment: I have only 2 GB. Are you using a server?? 24 GB?

Comment: It's just a desktop I built. I do quite a lot with it but it's undoubtedly more than I need. I think the most I've ever consciously *used* was 20GB but that was a one-off.

Comment: How much did it cost you ?