# Ubuntu 15.10 - high ram usage

Tags: 15.10, ram, swap, memory-usage

I am writing because I have no idea what going on with my favourite os, Ubuntu 15.10 with the kde desktop.
The problem affect ram usage in normal  work (chromium/firefox browser with few cards and flash). I have set the vm.swappiness parameter to 1. I have 8GB of ram, and  after few hours of work ubuntu use 90% of ram and 4GB of swap. 
It can be seen below after 2 hours of work:

```
root@celestia-laptop:/home/mariusz# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7866       7707        159       4230         42       4732
-/+ buffers/cache:       2932       4934
Swap:        16391        920      15471
```

When I switch off the swap the system is going crazy - it's very slow, and hard drive usage is 100%.
Maybe somebody have solution for my problem?

The output from the df -h command:

```
System plików  rozm. użyte dost. %uż. zamont. na
udev            3,9G  3,9G     0 100% /dev
tmpfs           787M  9,6M  778M   2% /run
/dev/sda10       36G   20G   15G  58% /
tmpfs           3,9G   78M  3,8G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3,9G     0  3,9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda8        80G   76G  4,9G  94% /media/BACKUP
/dev/sda9       282G  249G   20G  93% /media/DANE
/dev/sda2        96M   32M   65M  34% /boot/efi
tmpfs           787M     0  787M   0% /run/user/115
tmpfs           787M   46M  741M   6% /run/user/1000
```

the output of the htop command sorted by memory:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtFH9.png)

After kill all of browsers processes the output from the free -m command look like this.

```
root@celestia-laptop:/home/mariusz# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7866       4486       3380       3087         38       3549
-/+ buffers/cache:        899       6967
Swap:        16391       1013      15378
```

You can see, that ubuntu use almost 2GB of memory.

I solved the problem temporary by change default tmpfs file system from 50% to 20%. Before run the kde desktop I remount tmpfs and devfs using following commands:

```
mount -o remount,size=20% /dev/
mount -o remount,size=20% /dev/shm
mount -o remount,size=20% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

I am wonder if there is permanent way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High RAM usage.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/633018/high-ram-usage)

Comment: Can you add the output of `df` to your question?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command

```
sudo top
```

Find out the culprint process and then kill it

```
sudo kill -9 <pid>
```

[image]

Also look for some of the services that might be always running. For more details, refer to this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units)

Comment: The kill command do nothing, because this is not a solution. How can i use web browser if I kill it. But still if i kill browsers the free command looks like this: `RAM: total=7866   used=4486   free=3380 shared=3087   buffers=38   cached=3549 
-/+ buffers/cache:      used= 899       free=6967
Swap:        total=16391       used=1013      free=15378 `. You can see, that ubuntu use almost 2GB of memory

Comment: In the startup processes there is no additional programs than in clean install. I solved the problem temporary by change the default tmpfs from 50% to 20%. I don't know how but this helps and the system use 1GB of ram.