# Ubuntu using a lot of ram when idle

Tags: ram, memory-usage

I recently started to notice that ubuntu is using a lot of ram even when I'm idle. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and when uptime of only 10 hours ubuntu is using 1.9GB/8GB with/without extensions.

This is the screenshot of my system monitor(only application running is plank since it's my dock)

[image]

[image]

Here is the result of `free -m` when only spotify, chrome(5 tabs),discord and telegram is open(with 14 hours of uptime).

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      7738        5903         206         623        1628         943
Swap:     2047         443        1604
```

Here is the result of `free -m` when my pc is idle with uptime of 14 hours.

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       7738        2708        3767          86        1261        4676
Swap:      2047         204        1843
```

The ram usage has significantly risen from yesterday.

Is there anything I can do to avoid this much of ram usage?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [High RAM usage.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633018/high-ram-usage) In short: don't worry. Unused memory is wasted memory. The kernel is good at managing memory, and 8GiB is enough for a general desktop. You should pay attention to swap rate, not memory use.

Comment: I'm unable to use as many application as I used to. With only 4 chrome tabs+spotify, my system wasn't working properly using about 6GB ram, which is a lot more than it used to. I closed all application to find it's using 800MB than usual.

Comment: What's the output of `free -m` in a terminal, both in idle mode, and with enough applications to create problems?

Comment: I'm sorry. I wasn't able to reply yesterday but now I've added result of these in the question and the ram usage has significantly risen up from yesterday.